# SIGSEGV from spawn child_process in AWS Lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, child-process, aws-lambda, ffprobe

I'm trying to spawn a synchronous child process (to run ffprobe) in AWS Lambda function, but it dies almost instantly (200ms) with signal SIGSEGV.

My understanding of a segmentation fault is that it is a process that is trying to access memory it isn't allowed to access. I tried increasing the memory to 1024MB (I was using 128MB as each execution only uses about 56MB), but this didn't change anything.

I'm aware I'm not the only person who has had this issue: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=229397

Anyone know how to resolve this?

**Update 25/4/2016**

For clarity, the code I am running is:

```
import { spawnSync } from 'child_process';

exports.handler = (event, context) => {
  process.env.PATH = `${process.env.PATH}:${process.env.LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}`;
  const ffprobe = './ffprobe';

  const bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
  const key = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;
  console.log(`bucket: ${bucket}`);
  console.log(`key: ${key}`);

  const url = 'http://my-clip-url.com'; // An s3 presigned url.
    if (!url) {
      throw new Error('Clip does not exist.');
    }

    const command = `-show_format -show_streams -print_format json ${url}`;

    try {
      const child = spawnSync(ffprobe, command.split(' '));
      console.log(`stdout: ${child.stdout.toString()}`)
      console.log(`stderr: ${child.stderr.toString()}`)
      console.log(`status: ${child.status.toString()}`)
      console.log(`signal: ${child.signal.toString()}`)
    } catch (exception) {
      console.log(`Process crashed! Error: ${exception}`);
    }
};
```

The output of which is:

```
START RequestId: 6d72847 Version: $LATEST

2016-04-25T19:32:26.154Z    6d72847 stdout: 
2016-04-25T19:32:26.155Z    6d72847 stderr: 
2016-04-25T19:32:26.155Z    6d72847 status: 0
2016-04-25T19:32:26.155Z    6d72847 signal: SIGSEGV
END RequestId: 6d72847
REPORT RequestId: 6d72847   Duration: 4151.10 ms    Billed Duration: 4200 ms    Memory Size: 256 MB Max Memory Used: 84 MB
```

I am using the Serverless framework to babelify and deploy my code.

NOTE: I have tried running this binary on ami-bff32ccc instance on EC2 (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html) and it works. So it must be something I'm doing (how I'm executing ffprobe).

Comment: Did you upload ffmpeg and ffprobe to your AWS lambda?

Comment: Yeah it's there. I'm using the Serverless framework and have set the 'includePaths' property to include the ffprobe file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version of ffprobe I was using I got from [John Van Sickle's site](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) and while it worked when I ran it on Amazon Linux EC2 instances, it wouldn't work on AWS Lambda.

Following Jeff Learman's advice, I built my own version using [this wonderful script](https://github.com/markus-perl/ffmpeg-build-script) on the current version of the environment used by AWS Lambda [as described here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html). I then deployed it with my Lambda function and it worked first time! :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this.  Have your Lambda function spawn a bash shell that does this:

`ulimit -c unlimited
  cd /tmp
  $LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT/ffprobe ...`

Then check for a file named "/tmp/core" and if it exists, copy it to an S3 bucket (or whatever), and use gdb to analyse it on your development system or an EC2 host.  I haven't verified this myself, but I do know that by default ulimit will be zero and core files will dump to the current directory.  Note that these details are subject to change without notice (and if memory serves me, has changed recently.)

Of course, the "cd" could happen in the lambda function.  If nodejs provides a way to set ulimit, it could happen there, too.

[Edit: the correct pattern is /tmp/core.%e.%p, see "man core" to interpret.]

Comment: Thanks for your response, Jeff. I tried that, but the only file in `/tmp` is `-rw-------  1 sbx_user1052  494 9134080 Apr 28 21:58 core.ffprobe-static.12`. What is that file? Can that be of any use? For clarity, the command I ran was `'ulimit -c unlimited; cd /tmp; $LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT/ffprobe -version;`

Comment: That looks like a core file, though not quite what I expected.  Give it a try and let us know!

Comment: The pattern is /tmp/core.%e.%p (see "man core" to interpret).

Comment: Hey Jeff. I tried one of the core files I got on the same box Lambda runs on and all I got was this: https://gist.github.com/patoncrispy/24b203acd6563216883bf5379f50eab6. I presume the lack of output means the static build of ffprobe I'm using doesn't have debug enabled...?

Comment: Yup, that's what it means. :-(  Maybe you can build from source or get help from ffprobe users.

Comment: Hey Jeff, thank you so much for your help and advice! My apologies, but I accidentally gave the bounty to the other answer and I don't seem to be able to undo it. :( However, I wanted to offer my sincere thanks for your assistance and guidance. It's greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi, I don't deserve this bounty. Let's try to make something up to give it back to @JeffLearman

Comment: I've flagged my own answer to seek for moderation intervention.

Answer (score 1):

**Prolegomenom:**

I'm wondering whether should I post the following as a comment or as an answer. The reason why I wonder it's because I'm a bit confused about what you're actually asking. At a first read, it's obvious you want to overcome the error, but you aren't helping us to contextualize it by, for example, showing your code to us. Furthermore, the issue discussed in the thread you posted it's related, but the author is asking a more general question: "**How to debug the problem**", and I have an answer for that:

**Answer**:

The Lambda logs are available in CloudWatch. SIGSEGV is caused when youre trying to access something you aren't allowed (as you pointed), this could be because the memory is locked by another process, and sometimes because you don't have permissions to what you're accessing, or can access something so something gets set as nil which is later used as a memory address, etc. You could add log statements to your code to investigate what's actually happening down there in your function and read such logs afterwords using CloudWatch: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-functions-logs.html

**Conclusion**:

Your question can't be solved as you're not fully explaining the problem, but at least, I'm pointing you to how to investigate it:

1. Adding debug logs to your code
2. Track logs with CloudWatch

If you need more assistance, you could post your code.

Comment: Thanks for helping! I've updated my answer with example code and output logs.